# Use of rest api in salesforce?

Tags: rest-api

I am new to Salesforce. I want to learn about the rest api. What are its uses? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to create a REST API or call an existing one? Or both?

Comment: Google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 5):

Everything related to REST API can be found at this page below

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/REST_API

[image]

> 1)Supports both XML and JSON format
>
> 2)Preferred for mobile and web apps since JSON being Lighter the app runs smoother and faster
>
> 3)Since both REST and OAuth rely strongly on HTTP/S standards - it makes it very easy to find existing libraries to communicate with the API's for nearly any language

Answer (score 3):

> Since REST uses standard HTTP it is much simpler in just about every
>   way.   Creating clients, developing APIs, the documentation is much
>   easier to understand and there aren’t very many things that REST
>   doesn’t do easier/better than SOAP.
>
> REST permits many different data formats whereas SOAP only permits
>   XML.  While this may seem like it adds complexity to REST because you
>   need to handle multiple formats, in my experience it has actually been
>   quite beneficial.
>
> JSON usually is a better fit for data and parses much faster. REST
>   allows better support for browser clients due to its support for JSON.
>
> REST has better performance and scalability. REST reads can be cached,
>   SOAP based reads cannot be cached.
>
> It’s a bad argument (by authority), but it’s worth mentioning that
>   Yahoo uses REST for all their services including Flickr and
>   del.ici.ous. Amazon and EBay provide both though Amazon’s internal
>   usage is nearly all REST source.
>
> Google used to provide only SOAP for all their services, but in 2006
>   they deprecated in favour of REST source.
>
> It’s interesting how there has been an internal battle between rest vs
>   soap at amazon. For the most part REST dominates their architecture
>   for web services.